# Fibonacci Sequence and Time/Space Complexity explanation?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm a self-taught programmer/boot-camp graduate, and I was just asked to code a function for the Fibonacci sequence yesterday at an interview and realized how much I didn't know when asked about performance differences between:

1. using a for loop.
2. using recursion.

Here's my answer using a loop:

```
def fibonacci(n)
  first_value = 0
  second_value = 1
  final_value = nil
  if n == 0
    final_value = first_value
  elsif n == 1
    final_value = second_value
  else
    (n - 1).times do
      final_value = first_value + second_value
      first_value = second_value
      second_value = final_value
    end
  end
  final_value
end
```

Here was my answer for recursion at the time:

```
def fibonacci(n)
  if n == 0
    0
  elsif n ==1
    1
  else
    fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
  end
end
```

So he mentioned how it took `2^n` **_____** (fill in the blank) for recursion and only `n` **_____** for the loop. Then he asked about time/space complexity and I was a little lost.

I haven't picked up a book on time/space complexity yet. Would I learn this stuff in an algorithms book? I recently bought the "Algorithm Design Manual" but haven't opened it yet.

When he said `2^n` something, was he talking about time or space? Could someone explain the time/space complexity theory and differences using those two functions?

Comment: I suggest you give this a read. Its in C++, but thats essential for your understanding . [READ](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960109.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it

Comment: To compute fibonacci with a loop, you just need to iterate up to `N`, which implies `O(N)` in time and essentially no space needs. The recursive approach is going to need `O(2^n)` in **both** time and space. To see why, draw a hierarchical diagram of the recursive call stack for something like `fibonacci(6)` and notice how it does so much repetitive work.

Comment: This would be better asked on [programmers.se]. Stack Overflow is about practical programming problems. Programmers is about theories and programming in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will took `2^n` time and `n` space. Why? Because on each call it call itself twice and each of the children calls need nearly the same amount of time to complete. As of memory: each call need 1 memory unit. After call all used memory is released. So if you draw a call tree then you will see that height of this tree is linear function of `n`.